# Rails Dynamic Reloading Class.subclasses after removing class definitions with remove_const

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a following snippet that metaprogramming create a subclass of class `Vehicle`:

```
class Vehicle; end

klazz = Class.new(Vehicle)
Object.const_set('Car', klazz)
```

Nothing fancy here. As I expected, `Vehicle.subclasses` would returns me `[Car]` array.

Next, I removed the class Car definition with:

```
Object.send(:remove_const, :Car)
```

and to my surprise, the `subclasses` are not dynamically reloaded, as:

```
Vehicle.subclassess.count == 1
```

I'd love to know how I could reload the subclasses or if the way I use `remove_const` is wrong. TIA

Comment: Where is this `Vehicle.subclasses` method coming from? I don't have one.

Comment: `subclasses` is probably from `ActiveSupport`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it is from rails, please pardon me, it is not ruby only. So is there any way to retrieve subclasses of Vehicle with ruby?

Answer (score 1):

`subclasses` is not a part of pure Ruby, while `remove_const` is. What is probably going on here is that the `subclasses` method is implemented via a counter that gets incremented on the `inherited` hook. However, since removing constants is not something normally done inside of a code base, there is probably not a related decrement (I do not believe there is a hook for `class_removed`, so they couldn't have a related decrement easily).

Technically, you could rewrite `remove_const` to make it figure out what to decrement, but I don't think it would be worth it, nor would it be a smart move (monkey patching core methods is always questionable IMO).